How to config babel to compile import from ES6
I have a problem about config babel to compile import from ES6 javascript. I use babel.config.js
this is file wdio.conf.js, i want to compile import chai from "chai" but i am fail.
require('@babel/register')({
    rootMode: "upward",
});

const chai = require('chai')

exports.config = {
    //  
    // ====================
    // Runner Configuration
    // ====================
    // WebdriverIO supports running e2e tests as well as unit and component tests.
    runner: 'local',

this is babel.config.js
module.exports = {
    presets: [
        ['@babel/preset-env', {
            targets: {
                node: '20' // update with the target you are aiming for
            }
        }]
    ]
}

this is my error:
ERROR @wdio/config:ConfigParser: Failed loading configuration file: file:///D:/PVD_HOCTAP/Back%20End/Javascript/Automated_Testing_demo/wdio.conf.js: require() of ES Module D:\PVD_HOCTAP\Back End\Javascript\Automated_Testing_demo\node_modules\chai\chai.js from D:\PVD_HOCTAP\Back End\Javascript\Automated_Testing_demo\wdio.conf.js not supported.
I hope everyone will help me! Thank you so much!

Sorry about my mistake
this is error: ERROR @wdio/config:ConfigParser: Failed loading configuration file: file:///D:/PVD_HOCTAP/Back%20End/Javascript/Automated_Testing_demo/wdio.conf.js: require() of ES Module D:\PVD_HOCTAP\Back End\Javascript\Automated_Testing_demo\node_modules\chai\chai.js from D:\PVD_HOCTAP\Back End\Javascript\Automated_Testing_demo\wdio.conf.js not supported.

You can edit your question with the update, click the edit link below your question.  I know, it's not obvious with it been just link.
